# Dynamically add class name to div's through jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add class name to multiple div's dynamically through jquery.
My requirement is like
For example we have 10 divs

```html
<div class="sec"></div>
<div class="sec"></div>
<div class="sec"></div>
<div class="sec"></div>
<div class="sec"></div>
<div class="sec"></div>
<div class="sec"></div>
<div class="sec"></div>
<div class="sec"></div>
<div class="sec"></div>
```

i want to add class name dynamically for every three divs with counter as shown below.

```html
<div class="sec sec_1"></div>
<div class="sec sec_1"></div>
<div class="sec sec_1"></div>

<div class="sec sec_2"></div>
<div class="sec sec_2"></div>
<div class="sec sec_2"></div>

<div class="sec sec_3"></div>
<div class="sec sec_3"></div>
<div class="sec sec_3"></div>

<div class="sec sec_4"></div>
```

Please help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var counter = 0;
$("div").each(function(index) {
  if (index % 3 == 0) {
    counter++;
  }
  $(this).addClass('sec_' + counter);
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
var counter = 0;
$("div").each(function(index) {
  if (index % 3 == 0) {
    counter++;
  }
  $(this).addClass('sec_' + counter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sec">a</div>
<div class="sec">a</div>
<div class="sec">a</div>
<div class="sec">a</div>
<div class="sec">a</div>
<div class="sec">a</div>
<div class="sec">a</div>
<div class="sec">a</div>
<div class="sec">a</div>
<div class="sec">a</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Simple and perfect answer. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Just find all the divs with class name 'sec' then assign id to them by looping

```
var resCtr = 1
var indexCtr = 1
$('.sec').each(function(i, obj) {
      $(this).addClass('sec_' + indexCtr);
      if (resCtr == 3 ) {
         resCtr = 1;
         indexCtr++;
      }
      resCtr++;

});
```

Here is a working fiddle : [Auto assign Class](https://jsfiddle.net/fyfkf104/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I feel this  involves more lines of coding.

Comment: @UIBest just ok I dont have time to edit my answer but it still works

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use nested loop like this:

```
var ar=$("div.sec");
  var suffix=1;
  for(var i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
    for(var j=1;j<=3;j++){
        $(ar[i]).addClass("sec_"+suffix);//.text("sec_"+ suffix);
      i++
    }
    suffix++;
  }
```

Here is working <kbd>[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/2emv75h9/)</kbd>